# Creating SKNodes in a background task

Tags: sprite-kit

Is it ok to create a hierarchy of SKNodes and SKSpriteNodes in a background process **as long as I process the addChild call for that hierarchy in the main thread**?

I'm a bit worried about the texture cache etc. Maybe it's a bad idea?

I construct dynamic text blocks with hundreds of characters, and sometimes that results in a minor FPS dip. I would therefore like to build it in a background process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is ok loading and building object in a background task as long as you add them to the Scene only in the main thread.

### Pool of objects

> I construct dynamic text blocks with hundreds of characters [...]

If you are continuously **creating** and **destroying** many nodes/sprites, you should consider creating a pool of object.
This way you can reuse the nodes you remove from the scene and you can avoid many deallocation/allocation operations which are very expensive.

Comment: Thanks! The char sprites are pooled. :) Are you 100% sure about that it is ok? Is it even documented? No problem with e.g. loading of same texture simultaneously from different threads?